# Proxy Socket.io with NGINX

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

does anyone know how to proxy socket.io with nginx?

Nginx v1.13+

Socket.io v2.0.4

Nodejs v8.9.4

my current nginx server block.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name .domain-name.com;
    root "/home/vagrant/code/domain-name";

    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:6001";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/domain-name.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain-name.com.key;
}
```

I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error on the client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
# Sockets redirect
upstream sockets {
    server 127.0.0.1:6001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain-name.com;
    root /home/vagrant/code/domain-name;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $scheme://sockets;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/domain-name.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain-name.com.key;
}
```

Comment: Would have been nice if you would have actually added an answer that explains what changed and why instead of just posting final result. Not very helpful!